# Visual Studio 2019 does not pull required Docker images at project open

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

I am under the impression that Visual Studio should pull all the required Docker images at project startup; hence, I expect it download and start SQL Server and RabbitMQ images since they are defined in my docker compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  sql.data:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine

  projectname:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}projectname
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ProjectName/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - sql.data
      - rabbitmq
```

I see the following in `Container Tools` window when visual studio opens my project:

```sh
========== Checking for Container Prerequisites ==========
Verifying that Docker Desktop is installed...
Docker Desktop is installed.
========== Verifying that Docker Desktop is running... ==========
Verifying that Docker Desktop is running...
Docker Desktop is running.
========== Verifying Docker OS ==========
Verifying that Docker Desktop's operating system mode matches the project's target operating system...
Docker Desktop's operating system mode matches the project's target operating system.
========== Pulling Required Images ==========
Checking for missing Docker images...
Docker images are ready.
========== Warming up container(s) for DataCollector ==========
Starting up container(s)...
docker run -dt -v ...
Container started successfully.
========== Finished ==========
```

When I run `docker ps -a` in PowerShell, I see:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
a24958fbc70f        projectname:dev   "tail -f /dev/null"   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:56656->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:44396->443/tcp   intelligent_babbage
```

So obviously it has not pulled (and started) the RabbitMQ and SQL Server containers.

I checked the settings at `Tools > Options > Container Tools` and `Pull required Docker images on project open` is set to `True`.

I am puzzled why the containers are not pulled then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to change the start-up project to `DockerCompose`.